# Errors in Main activity class.

Tags: android

**The R.id fields are showing errors and so while saving it shows there in no fields as in xml. The Main activity class code is posted below plz help as m stuck in this only. on cleaning and build the R.java class is disappearing.Its showing No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/feedbackbutton') and also with the other fields in **

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.example.android.sec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendFeedback(View button) {

    }

    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    String name = nameField.getText().toString();
    final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    String email = emailField.getText().toString();
    final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
    String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();
    final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
    String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
    boolean bRequiresResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/feedbacktitle"
    android:textSize="10pt">
</TextView>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/feedbackname"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</EditText>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</EditText>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist">
</Spinner>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</EditText>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</CheckBox>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/feedbackbutton"
    android:onClick="sendFeedback"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Arrays.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="feedbacktypelist">
        <item>@string/feedbacktype1</item>
        <item>@string/feedbacktype2</item>
        <item>@string/feedbacktype3</item>
        <item>@string/feedbacktype4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Other string resources also defined in this file… -->
    <string name="feedbacktype1">Good</string>
    <string name="feedbacktype2">Very Good</string>
    <string name="feedbacktype3">Excellent</string>
    <string name="feedbacktype4">Bad</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your initialize to oncreate

```
EditText nameField,feedbackField;
Spinner feedbackSpinner;
CheckBox responseCheckbox; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName); 
     emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
     String email = emailField.getText().toString();
     feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
     String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();
     feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
     String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);

}
```

Edit:

Makes sure you have defined all the strings in strings.xml  that you use in layout xml

Comment: @user2764599 your initialization part is outside of any method. try the above now

Comment: there are 5 initializations Edit text name, edittextmail etc. should i move that whole block in oncreate method?

Comment: @user2764599 see the above edit. this just one mistake i could find. looking at the rest of the code

Comment: @user2764599 seems there are errors in your resources files. check your xmls for any errors if there are errors r.java will not be generated. looks like you are missing some entries in strings ,xml

Answer (score 0):

addd the resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="feedbackbutton">Button</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: in which xml should i add this button?

Comment: @user2764599 that is a resource not a button. you are referring string resource in your xml like `@string/feedbackbutton`. So make sure you have `<string name="feedbackbutton">Button</string>` in strings.xml. similarly for others. i suggest you see the docs.

Comment: @user Please follow the Raghunandan what he saying.

Comment: Bad XML block: header size 248 or total size 16005680 is larger than data size 0...... Why this error occurs??

Comment: Now console is not showing any error but R.java is not regenerating